# How does snapshotting interfere with parent/child relationships?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parent-child, snapshot

### Summary

1. Add a `childVC` to a `parentVC`
2. Snapshot `childVC.view`
3. It bugs.

Why?

### Situation

I've just encountered a strange behavior and I would like to know if it is normal or if it is a bug.

I have a view controller `childVC` which is a child of `parentVC`. When creating the parent/child relationship, my code is

```
    [parentVC addChildViewController:childVC] ;
    [parentVC.view addSubview:childVC.view] ;
    [childVC didMoveToParentViewController: parentVC] ;
```

Few lines further, I want to create a snapshot of `childVC.view`. My code is

```
UIView * view = childVC.view ;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.contentSize, NO, 0);
{
    [...]

    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds
               afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    [...]
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

### Bug

Then I have the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view
>   controller: should have parent
>   view controller:(null) but actual parent is:'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0260b466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x02290a97 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x0260b38d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141     3   UIKit
>   0x01136710 -[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   _associatedViewControllerForwardsAppearanceCallbacks:performHierarchyCheck:isRoot:]
>   + 352     4   UIKit                               0x01136b13 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 285   5   UIKit                               0x0114330a -[UIView(Internal)
>   _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 511     6   UIKit                               0x01136252 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56    7   UIKit
>   0x0114ab0e +[_UIReplicantView _pendingSnapshotOfTarget:snapshotBlock:]
>   + 584     8   UIKit                               0x011312fe -[UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:] + 287

### Question

Why is it so? Can I solve this issue?

### More details

Actually, `childVC.view` is a `UIScrollView` and the code for snapshotting is

```
UIScrollView * scrollView = (UIScrollView *)childVC.view;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, NO, 0);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = scrollView.frame;

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                            0,
                            scrollView.contentSize.width,
                            scrollView.contentSize.height);

    [scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect:scrollView.bounds
               afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Maybe that makes a big difference.

Comment: That's 3 years old, but it's happening to me today in Swift 4. Have you solved your issue since then?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Good luck.

Comment: this is the weirdest bug! it works exactly once for me & crashes on subsequent snapshots

Comment: I had exactly the same crash but with different circumstances. This happens when you snapshot a view without a window (e.g. `view.window == nil`)

Comment: I've run into this as well.  My solution is to remove the child from the parent, snapshot, then add it back to the parent.  I guess child viewControllers are like my kids - no snapshots please!

Comment: I had the same problem and solve it. To debug that print scrollView.window, if it's nil, somewhere in your hierarchy a view is not added to his supposed superview. In my case the topViewController of a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue today, when implementing a custom transition using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. The problem was that when I tried to snapshot the child view controller, its parent was not part of a view hierarchy yet.

The solution is to make sure that the parent's view has been added to a view hierarchy before you try to snapshot the child. In my case, I just needed to add the "to" view controller to the `transitionContext.containerView` first.

From your code snippet, I can't tell when you are trying to take the snapshot. But if it is before `viewDidAppear()`, it probably won't work.

Comment: You just save my life! Had an issue inside a custom transition as well, I just didn't get any error message or crash, only a messed up layout. Adding to the container first solved it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this crash when using `view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)` to capture child view controller's view before removing it from parent.

For me, passing `false` to `afterScreenUpdates` solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your parent view controller is getting deallocated and hence the `(null)` in the exception message?